# Counting unique characters in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, char

I have created a function that counts the number of unique characters in a 2D char array and the function returns true/false depending on whether the number of unique chars is higher or lower than the width or height of the grid.

I'm wondering if there is an easier way of implementing the uniqueChars function in c90.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAXGRIDHW 9

typedef enum bool{ false = 0, true = 1 } bool;

typedef struct node{
    char grid[MAXGRIDHW][MAXGRIDHW];
    int height;
    int width;
    int parent;
} Node;

bool uniqueChars(Node* b);
void setHeightWidth(Node* b, int h, int w);
void clearNode(Node* b);

int main (void)
{
    Node shelf1[10];

    char testArr2[3][4] = {{"z.."},
                           {"q.."},
                           {"z.."}};    

   clearNode(&shelf1[2]);

   memcpy(&shelf1[2].grid, testArr2, 7);

   setHeightWidth(&shelf1[2], 3, 4);

   assert(uniqueChars(&shelf1[2]) == true);

   return 0;
}

bool uniqueChars(Node* b)
{
    int i, j, chars = 0;
    bool appears;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXGRIDHW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAXGRIDHW; j++) {
            b->grid[i][j] = toupper(b->grid[i][j]); 
            if (b->grid[j] == b->grid[i]) {
               appears = true;
               break;
            }
        }
        if (!appears) {
            chars++;
        }
    }

    if (b->height < chars || b->width < chars) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}



void setHeightWidth(Node* b, int h, int w)
{
    b->height = h;
    b->width = w;
}
```

Comment: Your `uniqueChars` is wrong because 1. The condition `b->grid[j] == b->grid[i]` is comparing pointers. It will always be true at the first iteration `i = 0, j = 0` and therefore is meaningless. 2. Value of `appears` may be used without being initialized after fixing that. Values of uninitialized non-static local variables are indeterminate and using such values invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: How do I go about remedying issue 1? j = i + 1?

Comment: Should `uniqueChars` really be modifying the contents of the grid using `toupper()`? Shouldn't `uniqueChars` be using the set height and width of the grid, rather than the maximum height and width?

Comment: I am intending on moving `toupper()` to another function later, I just wanted instances of the same letter, just upper and lowercase, treated as 1. And yes that seems obvious now that I should use the height/width I've actually set

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of occurrences of each character:

```
int numchars[256];
memset(numchars, 0, 256*sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < MAXGRIDHW; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXGRIDHW; j++) {
        ++numchars[toupper(b->grid[i][j])];
    }
}
```

And then traverse the numchars array to see which chars occur only once.